# Using Node module with out type defination in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

I have  written a very simple node module [ npm install twinconsole ] and published to npm.

I also included browser [build](https://npmcdn.com/twinconsole@1.2.1/dist/index.umd.min.js) ( umd module ) so that it can be 
used from browser as well.

Below is node module related code

```
module.exports.print = msg => {
console.log(msg);
}
```

Now I would like to use this node module from my Angular 2 typescript application, to do that

1. I have included below CDN file in index.html.

   < script src="https://npmcdn.com/twinconsole@1.2.1/dist/index.umd.min.js">

What is that I need to do so that print() function exported in node module can be used in below root component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var twinconsole: any;  // ADDEED THIS LINE , IS THIS CORRECT ?


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Comment: Yes your declare statement should work just fine. I've done similar declarations of CryptoJS for encryption. I find it useful to create an interface for the declared vars if their APIs are more extensive. This allows editors like VSCode to still provide a nice development experience because they expose the interface via autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

//define interface to get "intellisense" aka autocomplete and type errors
interface TwinConsole{
  print(msg:string);
}

declare var twinconsole: TwinConsole;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'app works!';
}
```